# "Too Large Data" error on my master spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a master with all this tabs in it but it worked until tab 36 after that it just dosen't update the new tab in to the master.

Formula:
`=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(B3,B4&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,C4&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,D4&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,E4&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,F4&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,G4&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,H4&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,I4&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,J4&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,K4&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,L4&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,M4&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,N4&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,O4&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,B5&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,C5&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,D5&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,E5&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,F5&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,G5&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,H5&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,I5&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,J5&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,K5&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,L5&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,M5&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,N5&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,O5&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,B6&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,C6&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,D6&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,E6&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,F6&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,G6&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,H6&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,I6&"!A2:M");IMPORTRANGE(B3,J6&"!A2:M")},"select * where Col1 is not null")`

I just want to make sure all new tabs work I need to be able to include 50 tabs on the same master sheet.

Comment: How much total cells there is in your sheet from all tabs? https://support.google.com/docs/thread/71943617/what-is-the-tab-limit-for-a-google-sheet-do-i-lose-my-tabs-while-creating-new-ones?hl=en

Comment: 23.962 rows X 13 columns = 311,506 cels